# New LED 3rd brake light stops working

Tags: gmc, tail-lights, led, sierra

Swapped out LED taillights and third brake light on my '05 Sierra. Tail lights work fine but the third brake light will work when first plugged in but after a short while the cab lights don't work.

Comment: If you pull the LED out and replace, then it works again the first time?

Comment: Want to clarify - does the brake light work more than once? Do the cab lights stop working when the brake light stood?