# After market lights

Tags: lights

My aftermarket led lights work at first but if I turn them on after a short period of time they don't? if I plug stock third brake light back in they work  fine?

Comment: Which light is it? Brake lights?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [this question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/33346/new-led-3rd-brake-light-stops-working).